# helm or operator with required function

Tags: kubernetes, helm3

I have to check for mandatory values based on some condition.
My *values.yaml* is as below

```yaml
id: 3
test:
 id: 2
 test1:
  id: 1
```

In my template, I need to check if `id` is present at `.Values.test.test1.id` and assign that value. If not fall back to `.Values.test.id` and at last `.Values.id`. But `id` has to be mandatory and I need to use required function.

My template is as below

```
{{- if .Values.test.test1.id }}
<assign> {{ .Values.test.test1.id }}
{{- else }}
{{- $id := .Values.test.id }}
{{- $id2 := .Values.id }}
<assign> <need to check required with or of $id $id2> </assign>
{{- end }}
```

I know this can be solved with one `elseif` in between `if` and `else`. But I need to repeat the same logic for many ids.
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a perfect fit for the [`coalesce` function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#coalesce), which

> takes a list of values and returns the first non-empty one.

<sup>*Source: https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#coalesce*</sup>

You will also need to use the [`default` function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-default-function) to convert the cases when the `test` or `test.test1` dictionaries are not defined.

All this together, gives:

```
{{- $test := .Values.test | default dict -}}
{{- $test1 := $test.test1 | default dict -}}
{{- $id := required "Please provide an ID" (
  coalesce $test1.id $test.id .Values.id
) -}}
id: {{ $id }}
```

And here are the test cases and results:

- Gives:

  ```yaml
  id: 1
  ```

  when *values.yaml* is

  ```yaml
  id: 3
  test:
    id: 2
    test1:
      id: 1
  ```
- Gives:

  ```yaml
  id: 2
  ```

  when *values.yaml* is

  ```yaml
  id: 3
  test:
    id: 2
  ```
- Gives:

  ```yaml
  id: 3
  ```

  when *values.yaml* is

  ```yaml
  id: 3
  ```
- Gives:

  ```
  Error: execution error at (demo/templates/test.yaml:3:11): 
    Please provide an ID
  ```

  when *values.yaml* is an empty file